# ImportError: No module named numpy - Google Cloud Dataproc when using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, importerror, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

When starting Jupyter Notebook on Google Dataproc, importing modules fails. I have tried to install the modules using different commands. Some examples:

```
import os
os.sytem("sudo apt-get install python-numpy")
os.system("sudo pip install numpy") #after having installed pip
os.system("sudo pip install python-numpy") #after having installed pip

import numpy
```

None of the above examples work and return an import error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtJEC.png)

When using command line I am able to install modules, but still the import error remains. I guess I am installing modules in a wrong location.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you installing Jupyter on Cloud Dataproc? Are you using the Jupyter initialization action (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/jupyter) or something else?

Comment: I used the initialization actions as described on github. I tried with initialization actions for Jupyter and Jupyter and conda-bootstrap. Both have te same problem. Note: I am using the PySpark Kernel. Maybe I am installing the modules in a wrong location? What is the path for python (pyspark) used in Jupyter? How can I install the modules for this version? My gcloud create command:

Comment: `gcloud dataproc clusters create test --zone=europe-west1-d  --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 --master-boot-disk-size 100 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 50 --project myproject --bucket mybucket --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh`

Comment: When using `os.system("sudo apt-get install python-pip -y")` and `os.system("sudo pip install numpy")`, both lines return 0, indicating the execution was succesful. Still import numpy returns the same import error.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

os.system("sudo apt-get install python-pandas -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-numpy -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-scipy -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-sklearn -y")

import pandas
import numpy
import scipy
import sklearn
```

If any one has a more elegant solution, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Stijn, Does your method above work across all worker nodes in the dataproc cluster or just the master node?

Comment: I guess this only installs the modeles on the master node. The way I am installing the modules now is by saving them in a google storage bucket and afterwards copying them to a location in belonging to the path by using a initialization-action. `if gsutil -q stat "gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/modules/**"; then`
    `echo "Pulling modules directory to cluster master and worker nodes..."`
 `gsutil -m cp -r gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/modules/* /usr/local/bin/miniconda/lib/python2.7` 
`fì`

Comment: Does your initialisation script include jupyter notebook and would you be willing to share it?

Comment: I putted the script in the answer below. It is just the standard initialization script for Juoyter with some modification for copying google storage content to the dataproc machines. Please keep in mind you should copy the modules you want to use into 'gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/modules/'.

Answer (score 1):

Try `conda install numpy` as Google's jupyter init script is using conda.
I personally prefer to have my own init scripts so I can have more control.

Comment: Nope, it should be run in your custom init-action script using --initialization-actions option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to execute the following command ?

```
pip install ipython[numpy]
```

Comment: I just tested "sudo pip install ipython[numpy]" in the master's command line and via os.system() in Jupyter both fail.  Error message in command line:

Comment: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle) ...

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2409, in requires
    "%s has no such extra feature %r" % (self, ext)
UnknownExtra: ipython 5.0.0 has no such extra feature 'numpy'
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    set -e

    ROLE=$(curl -f -s -H Metadata-Flavor:Google http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/dataproc-role)
    INIT_ACTIONS_REPO=$(curl -f -s -H Metadata-Flavor:Google http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/INIT_ACTIONS_REPO || true)
    INIT_ACTIONS_REPO="${INIT_ACTIONS_REPO:-https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git}"
    INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH=$(curl -f -s -H Metadata-Flavor:Google http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH || true)
    INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH="${INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH:-master}"
    DATAPROC_BUCKET=$(curl -f -s -H Metadata-Flavor:Google http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/dataproc-bucket)

    echo "Cloning fresh dataproc-initialization-actions from repo $INIT_ACTIONS_REPO and branch $INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH..."
    git clone -b "$INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH" --single-branch $INIT_ACTIONS_REPO
    # Ensure we have conda installed.
    ./dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/bootstrap-conda.sh
    #./dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/install-conda-env.sh

    source /etc/profile.d/conda_config.sh

    if [[ "${ROLE}" == 'Master' ]]; then
        conda install jupyter

        if gsutil -q stat "gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/notebooks/**"; then
           echo "Pulling notebooks directory to cluster master node..."
           gsutil -m cp -r gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/notebooks /root/
        fi

        ./dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/internal/setup-jupyter-kernel.sh
        ./dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/internal/launch-jupyter-kernel.sh
     fi

     if gsutil -q stat "gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/scripts/**"; then
         echo "Pulling scripts directory to cluster master and worker nodes..."
         gsutil -m cp -r gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/scripts/*     /usr/local/bin/miniconda/lib/python2.7
     fi 

     if gsutil -q stat "gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/modules/**"; then
        echo "Pulling modules directory to cluster master and worker nodes..."
        gsutil -m cp -r gs://$DATAPROC_BUCKET/modules/*    /usr/local/bin/miniconda/lib/python2.7   
     fi 

     echo "Completed installing Jupyter!"

# Install Jupyter extensions (if desired)
# TODO: document this in readme
if [[ ! -v $INSTALL_JUPYTER_EXT ]]
    then
    INSTALL_JUPYTER_EXT=false
fi
if [[ "$INSTALL_JUPYTER_EXT" = true ]]
then
    echo "Installing Jupyter Notebook extensions..."
    ./dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/internal/bootstrap-jupyter-ext.sh
    echo "Jupyter Notebook extensions installed!"
fi
```

Comment: You should add some explanation on what you are doing with this script

Comment: Actually, this is just the Jupyter initialization scripts as could be found on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/jupyter. The only things I added is the three `gsutil -m -cp -r` lines that copies the content from the gs bucket to the machines. This is indicated by for example  `echo "Pulling modules directory to cluster master and worker nodes..."`