# "No module named numpy..." error on google-data-proc , how to upgrade numpy on google-data-proc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I keep getting this error when I run my notebook on Google-Cloud-Data-Proc

```
import numpy as np
ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function _parse_datatype_json_string at 0x7fc294e25230>.......
```

But don't get the error when running locally with same python 2.7

I found that version on my local is
`numpy.version.version`
**'1.11.1'**

but on google-data-proc it is older
**'1.8.2' **

As mentioned in other answers [ImportError: No module named numpy - Google Cloud Dataproc when using Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572287/importerror-no-module-named-numpy-google-cloud-dataproc-when-using-jupyter-no) I tried this to upgrade

```
 import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

os.system("sudo apt-get install python-pandas -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-numpy -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-scipy -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-sklearn -y")

import pandas
import numpy
import scipy
import sklearn
```

I still get 1.8.2 version

pip command doesn't have permission on google-data-proc

tried pip with sudo, that too didn't work.

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/easy-install.pth'
my-user-name@cluster-name-1-m:~$ sudo pip install numpy
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: We've now [added a metadata option](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/commit/c1a61bfc75a2605e19503ccb402f2c7fab663706) `JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES` to automatically pre-install packages through `conda` during the Jupyter setup. As now covered by the [examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/jupyter#jupyter-notebook), the preferred way to get your packages installed is with:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-cluster \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
    --metadata JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:pandas:scikit-learn:scipy
```

**In the absence of using this metadata value, historical answer below for posterity and more internal details:**

Dataproc's jupyter initialization action also installs `conda`, so on your master node you can just run:

```
sudo su
conda install numpy
```

Depending on how it's used you may also need it on your worker nodes; you can customize the main `jupyter.sh` script adding the line `conda install numpy` anywhere after the `/dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/bootstrap-conda.sh` line and re-upload your custom init action to GCS somewhere to specify that instead of `gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh` to automatically install it on your deployments. Something like:

```
gsutil cp gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh .
echo "conda install numpy >> jupyter.sh"
gsutil cp jupyter.sh gs://my-bucket/jupyter_with_numpy.sh
gcloud dataproc clusters crreate my-cluster \
    --initialization-actions gs://my-bucket/jupyter_with_numpy.sh
```

Finally, you can also use the built-in package manager in the Jupyter UI to browse and install conda packages:

[image: Select Conda Packages menu dropdown from Kernel menu]

[image: Browse Conda packages]

[image: Install Conda packages]

Comment: I already tried it, I get this error `my-user-name@my-cluster-name-m:~$ sudo conda install numpy
sudo: conda: command not found`

Comment: Ah interesting. Seems to have to do with bash login profiles. What if you first run `sudo su` and then run `conda install numpy`?

Comment: But if I run it without `sudo`, it runs but in end it throws this error `CondaIOError: IO error: Missing write permissions in: /usr/local/bin/miniconda`

Comment: yes, it worked with sudo su. I guess, I will need to do same for ALL workers :(

Comment: oh wait, I re-checked version on notebook by `numpy.version.version` it still shows 1.8.2, do I need to restart notebook or something?

Comment: Hmm, strange. On my newly deployed cluster I see `>>> numpy.version.version
'1.11.2'` Are you working on an older cluster? Is it using Dataproc version 1.1?

Comment: Another easier way to manage packages might be to use Jupyter's built-in `Kernel -> Conda Packages` menu option.

Comment: that might be it, how to figure out what dataproc version I am running? I just started one today using steps listed here https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130561/discussion-between-dennis-huo-and-watt).

Comment: Hi, I have some following-up questions for this answer. 1) If I ssh to master node and install a package with conda or pip, that should only install the package in master node but not worker nodes. Is there a way that I can install packages on all nodes of cluster after dataproc cluster creation? 2) I didn't see the 'Conda packages' option under Kernel in my Jupyter. (My Jupyter is installed as an optional component of cluster). How can I get it? 3) Does that 'Conda packages' install packages in master node only, or in all nodes? I've been blocked by this package installation and thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no built-in way to run extra actions on all nodes after cluster creation (in particular, if such a command ran those actions one time on all the nodes, what happens if you add nodes to the cluster?). However, one possible solution is to write a meta-init-action which polls HDFS for scripts to run on all nodes and registers as a systemd service, similar to how I wrote "sync-jars.sh" in here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions -- basically, you'd have something on all nodes poll hdfs for scripts, and you just upload a script

Comment: Such an approach would support adding nodes to clusters too. Keep in mind it's important to poll on HDFS in this case instead of polling directly on GCS because GCS will charge $0.05 for every [10,000 list operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) which could add up to a lot of money if you don't keep track.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Btw, is the link the one you meant? I didn't see a sync-jars.sh example in that page.

Comment: Oops, right, meant to link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739463/cant-add-jars-pyspark-in-jupyter-of-google-dataproc/55859782#55859782