# How to run a Notebook on dataproc using composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I have a Jupyter notebook on `dataproc` which is using dataproc for processing. I have also stored this notebook on gcs at a location "gc:/bucket/...".

I'd like to create a Composer workflow to run this notebook on my existing dataproc cluster. Is that possible in GCP?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a Jupyter notebook programatically in Dataproc. An approach that you can take is to extract the code from the notebook and then submit it as a job in your cluster from Composer, for example, using the [DataprocPySparkOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator).

Comment: what if I use Papermill?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but yes, it should work. You can install jupyter and papermill in the dataproc cluster, and then use Composer to submit a Pig job (a bash command can be submitted as a pig sh job) in the cluster to use papermill. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56034588/7517757 for reference on how to submit the Pig job.